# PowerShell Move-Item to folders efficiently

Tags: powershell

I am trying to to create an efficient PowerShell script that moves a list of files of .xlsx extension into another folder. About 30 files get generated with the current month and year at the end e.g "- January 2018"  into this folder path \otnas6uk\sd.test-it.com$\PROJECTS\

Ideally if the Month and Year could be defined at the start so it loops through all files in the root directory and moves them to the correct folder listed.

This is pseudocode of how I think it could work.

$month = "February"
$year = "2018"

```
Move-Item -Path "\\otnas6uk\sd.test-it.com$\PROJECTS\\Zentic Report - $month $year.xlsx" -Destination  \\zemnas\sd.Zentic-test.com$\Technology\Reports
```

All files and destinations would be predefined with only the month and year used as a parameter.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add a few details? Add an example of what kind of files you got and what is the desired output. If there are some edge cases (say, don't move file X because of Y), add those too.

Comment: Updated for you. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
$oldFolder = '\\otnas6uk\sd.test-it.com$\PROJECTS\\Zentic Report'
$jan2018Folder = '\otnas6uk\sd.test-it.com$\PROJECTS'

# Get a list of the files ending with .xlsx
$files = Get-ChildItem $oldFolder | Where { $_.Extension -eq '.xlsx' }

# Move each file over to the new directory
foreach ($file in $files) {
    # Repeat if for all months
    if ($file.Name -like '*January*' -and $file.Name -like '*2018*') {
        $newPath = "$jan2018Folder\$($file.Name)"
    }
    Move-Item $file $newPath
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This would work if it was just one folder I was concerned about but there will be over 30 files in this folder going to 30 different folder locations. How could this be accommodated for each different file and folder destination?

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, you want to move each file to a different folder based on the month included in the name of the file? I've added an if statement that will check for the month and will move the file to its appropriate folder. You'll have to fill in the rest of the months yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that is correct. How does your script workif two different file names go to two different folders? Will this not just work for one file as the oldFolder has been defined? I was going to list all filepaths and their destination and the loop would just pass through the selected month and year to identify the correct file.

Comment: I'm assuming that all the files you want to move are in the same directory, which is `$oldFolder`. This script gets all the files in that folder, loops through them and moves them to the appropriate folder based on their name. If all the files you want to move start in different folders as well, you'd need more loops.

Comment: No perhaps I didn't make that clear. Each file goes to a different folder location.

Comment: But are all files in the same folder to begin with?

Comment: Yes all files are initially in the same folder '\otnas6uk\sd.test-it.com$\PROJECTS' but where should I list each file and its destination? That's what I'm struggling to get my head around. Much appreciate yo help on this. Can I not list all 30 files with the destination and use $month and $year for each file name and it will pick up each file for the selected month?

Comment: Each of the 30 files you want to move is stored in the `$files` variable. Each destination would have to be its own variable (similar to the `$jan2018Folder` variable). If you add another if statement for each month, this script will loop through each file you want to move and move it to the correct folder based on the month. You can call `Move-Item` individually thirty times for each file, but if you're repeating something that many times, it's better to put it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
#region inputs
$month = 12
$year = 2018
$sourceDirectory      = "C:\temp"
$destinationDirectory = "C:\destination"
$fileFilter = "*.xlsx"
#endregion

#region input validation
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $sourceDirectory)) {
    throw "Can't find source directory"
}

# Month has to be between 1 and 12
if ($month -lt  1 -or
    $month -gt 12
) {
    throw "BAD MONTH!"
}

# Recent-ish years only
if ($year -lt ((Get-Date).Year - 1) -or
    $year -gt ((Get-Date).Year + 2)
) {
    throw "BAD YEAR!"
}
#region

#region destination

# Build up new folder path
$destinationDirectory = Join-Path -Path $destinationDirectory -ChildPath $year
$destinationDirectory = Join-Path -Path $destinationDirectory -ChildPath $month

#Create destination if not exists
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $destinationDirectory)) {
    New-Item -Path $destinationDirectory -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
}
#endregion

#region move files
Get-childItem -Path $sourceDirectory -File -Filter $fileFilter |
    Move-Item -Destination $destinationDirectory
#engregion
```

Comment: Just re-read the requirements and realise I'm not quite en pointe... But there should be enough useful stuff in there to _illustrate_ how you could get to your solution. If you give me a bit of detail around what's not quite right I can update my answer `:-)`

Comment: Yes it is very useful but I am very new to PowerShell so I am not confident to take what you've used and reapply it. All 30 files get generated each month into one folder with a 'month year' added to the file name to mark is as identifiable. By listing all 30 filenames and their corresponding folder like in the above example and instead of specifying the actual month and year pass through these variables form your assignment at the start. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

May be this should help move forward:

```
$Month = "Febuary";

$Year = "2018"

dir .\excelfiles\*$Month*$Year.xlsx|%{move-item -Path $_.FullName -Destination .\Destination.Folder}
```